# how does kubernetes detect docker daemon

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I'm using coreos tectonic sandbox. My deployment.yaml file contains the container which should detect the docker daemon running on host via kubernetes. 
The container uses docker daemon to identify docker events. For some reason docker daemon is not getting detected.

```
deployment.yaml

containers: 
  - name: idn-docker
    image: sample/id-docker:latest
      - name: docker-socket
        mountpath: /var/run/docker.sock
```

can some please help me identify what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

For run Docker in a Docker, you have 2 options - DooD (Docker out of Docker) and DinD (Docker in Docker). I think you need a first because you need access to events on a host machine.

Here is a good [article](https://applatix.com/case-docker-docker-kubernetes-part-2/) about both schemes.

Example of pod's configuration:

```
apiVersion: v1 
kind: Pod 
metadata: 
  name: idn-docker 
spec: 
  containers: 
  - name: idn-docker
    image: sample/id-docker:latest
    volumeMounts: 
      - mountPath: /var/run 
        name: docker-sock 
volumes: 
  - name: docker-sock 
    hostPath: 
        path: /var/run
```

You can use a `containers` section from an example in your deployment because of its structure in `template` section is the same Pod template as a separate pod configuration.

But, please keep in mind, that solution will have some limitations:

> *Pod Networking* - Cannot access the container using Pod IP.
>
> *Pod Lifecycle* - On Pod termination, this container will keep running especially if the container was started with -d flag.
>
> *Pod Cleanup* - Graph storage will not be clean up after pod terminates.
>
> *Scheduling and Resource Utilization* - Cpu and Memory requested by Pod, will only be for the Pod and not the container spawned from the Pod. Also, limits on CPU and memory settings for the Pod will not be inherited by the spawned container.

Answer (score 0):

### Securing Docker Socket

As in [Why we don't let non-root users run Docker in CentOS, Fedora, or RHEL](http://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/08/why-we-dont-let-non-root-users-run-docker-in-centos-fedora-or-rhel/), CoreOS by default does not have docker group and tries to prevent accesses to the docker socket by limiting accesses to root to be secure.

A Kuberneses pod which is a Docker container process will not run as root by default, and also SELinux labels will prevent the pods/containers from accessing the docker socket. Check with the pod process with ps -Z and the docker socket with ls -Z to verify the labels.

Allowing the access to Docker socket from a container is a security risk, but if it is mandatory to do so for some reason, one way is to run the pod as privileged using security context, and make the pod process run as root (with risks).

```
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
```

Not sure with tectonic but OpenShift by default prevents using hostPath mount and tectonic may have similar. Another stuff look into is the service account used for the pod and the role/bindings to the account.

Comment: Hi @mon. I don't think that you need to run container in privileged mod just for access to the docker socket and it has a [docker group](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/hardening-guide.html#docker-daemon). So I think it will be enough to just mount a docker socket into the container. Moreover, you can customize `docker.socket` service to allow user which K8s use to run pods to access that socket. Or use a separate user and `runAsUser` [option](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#set-the-security-context-for-a-pod).

Comment: BTW, OpenShift has `HostPath` volume type in documentation and looks like it works as expected and I cannot find any prevents using it. The only thing which you need, possibly, do is to make a right SELinux setting for access to the directories you need. Can you please explain what you mean by "prevents using hostPath mount"?

Comment: @AntonKostenko, look into SCC please. hostPath by default is not allowed unless you explicitly grant with oc adm policy add-scc-to-user.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I found it [here](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.0/admin_guide/manage_scc.html#use-the-hostpath-volume-plugin).